# How to Implement IComparable interface?

Tags: c#, interface, icomparable

I am populating an array with instances of a class:

```
BankAccount[] a;
. . .

a = new BankAccount[]
{
    new BankAccount("George Smith", 500m),
    new BankAccount("Sid Zimmerman", 300m)
};
```

Once I populate this array, I would like to sort it by balance amounts. In order to do that, I would like to be able to check whether each element is sortable using `IComparable`. 
I need to do this using interfaces. So far I have the following code:

```
public interface IComparable
{
    decimal CompareTo(BankAccount obj);
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right solution.  Any advice?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

You should not define `IComparable` yourself. It is already defined. Rather, you need to *implement* `IComparable` on your `BankAccount` class.

Where you defined the `class BankAccount`, make sure it implements the `IComparable` interface. Then write `BankAccount.CompareTo` to compare the balance amounts of the two objects.

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount>
{
    [...]

    public int CompareTo(BankAccount that)
    {
        if (this.Balance <  that.Balance) return -1;
        if (this.Balance == that.Balance) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit** to show Jeffrey L Whitledge's solution from comments:

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount>
{
    [...]

    public int CompareTo(BankAccount that)
    {
        return this.Balance.CompareTo(that.Balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry can u give me an example of how i would implement it

Comment: I like `return this.Balance.CompareTo(that.Balance);`

Comment: @i am a girl - I am not sure what you mean. Perhaps you are not clear on which part of the code I was replacing. I will put all of it in the comment, then: `public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount> { [...] int CompareTo(BankAccount that) { return this.Balance.CompareTo(that.Balance); } }` Is that more clear?

Comment: Another way would be `return Balance - that.Balance;`

Comment: In the 1st version, it should be `this.Balance < that.Balance` to sort by balance ascending. -1 = this is less than that, 0 = this is equal to that, 1 = this is greater than that

Comment: @fbiagi Thank you for bringing this to attention. Most people think `IComparable` always returns either -1, 0 or 1, but there is nothing in the rules that says `IComparable` will return -1 or 1. The definition of `IComparable` states that it will return a number less than zero or a number more than zero, meaning it is perfectly acceptable for someone to use subtraction to implement `CompareTo`. Some people are unaware of this and start using switch statements on `IComparable.CompareTo`, which is incorrect and is liable to break on certain comparisons.

Comment: You may also want to return 1 for a null `that` object if you feel a `null` pointer has less intrinsic value. The example above will throw on a null and I'm not sure this is desirable during sort ops.

Comment: Interface implementation cannot be public if I remember right

Comment: I believe you have your results backwards.  If the current objects value is GREATER than the one being compared to, then it should return 1.  You have it returning -1.

Comment: `return Balance - that.Balance` is not a good idea if the balance ever nears the limits of its type, because overflow could give you the wrong results.  For example, if Balance were a `short`, and `this.Balance` was 32700 and `that.Balance` was -100, the result of the subtraction would be -32736, when clearly the result of `CompareTo` should be a positive number.  Similarly, if Balance is a `ushort`, the result of the subtraction can never be negative, which is also clearly wrong.

Comment: I fixed the mistake in the first example implementation – changed `>` to `<`. This is the first Google result for "implement icomparable", so it should probably be correct.

Comment: Such a little beauty, with "this" and "that". Unfortunately, in modern times... "this" creates an IDE warning that it's unnecessary, and "that" doesn't work OOTB due to nullability...

Comment: @Eike:  This answer was written 12 years ago.  I'm not surprised that it is no longer ideal code.  But it was good at the time it was written.

Comment: @abelenky My problem is I feel it's just perfect code, which my analyzers nowadays won't let me go through with... (And I feel SO questions are never dead. ;) )

Answer (score 18):

`IComparable` already exists in .NET with this definition of CompareTo

```
int CompareTo(Object obj)
```

You are not supposed to create the interface -- you are supposed to implement it.

```
public class BankAccount : IComparable {

    int CompareTo(Object obj) {
           // return Less than zero if this object 
           // is less than the object specified by the CompareTo method.

           // return Zero if this object is equal to the object 
           // specified by the CompareTo method.

           // return Greater than zero if this object is greater than 
           // the object specified by the CompareTo method.
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry can u give me an example of how i would implement it

Comment: And what if obj is `null` or of another type than `BankAccount`? EDIT: According to MSDN here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1 : throw an `ArgumentException`.

Answer (score 17):

Do you want to *destructively* sort the array? That is, do you want to actually change the order of the items in the array? Or do you just want a list of the items in a particular order, without destroying the original order?

I would suggest that it is almost always better to do the latter. Consider using LINQ for a non-destructive ordering. (And consider using a more meaningful variable name than "a".)

```
BankAccount[] bankAccounts = { whatever };
var sortedByBalance = from bankAccount in bankAccounts 
                      orderby bankAccount.Balance 
                      select bankAccount;
Display(sortedByBalance);
```

Comment: i want to destruct it implementing icompare

Comment: @Lippert: While this is a very valid response, it seems from the discussion that the OP barely understands what it means to implement an interface. She's probably not yet ready for the level of questions you're asking.

Comment: Hi Eric, what's the best practice for dealing with `null` when implementing `IComparable<T>` and subclassing `Comparer<T>` assuming `T` is a reference type? Does it depend on the user case or it's normally better to throw exception since the real comparison logic is often forwarded to some property on `T`.

Comment: @stt106: That sounds like a question; consider posting it as a question. Short answer: I would implement a total order on all possible values, including null. Traditionally null is smaller than all other possibilities.  That said, it might be sensible to throw an exception if you think that it is always *wrong* for a null to be provided.

Answer (score 11):

An alternative is to use LINQ and skip implementing IComparable altogether:

```
BankAccount[] sorted = a.OrderBy(ba => ba.Balance).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 8):

There is already [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), but you should ideally support both `IComparable<T>` and `IComparable`. Using the inbuilt `Comparer<T>.Default` is generally an easier option. `Array.Sort`, for example, will accept such a comparer.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to compare multiple fields, you can get some help from the compiler by using the new tuple syntax:

```cs
public int CompareTo(BankAccount other) =>
  (Name, Balance).CompareTo(
    (other.Name, other.Balance));
```

This scales to any number of properties, and it will compare them one-by-one as you would expect, saving you from having to implement many if-statements.

Note that you can use this tuple syntax to implement other members as well, for example `GetHashCode`. Just construct the tuple and call `GetHashCode` on it.

Comment: Good solution for multi fields.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to sort these `BankAccounts`, use `LINQ` like following

```
BankAccount[] a = new BankAccount[]
{
    new BankAccount("George Smith", 500m),
    new BankAccount("Sid Zimmerman", 300m)
};

a = a.OrderBy(bank => bank.Balance).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to the multiple fields solution provided by [@Daniel Lidström](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69735536/3142139) by using tuple:

```cs
   public static void Main1()
        {
            BankAccount[] accounts = new BankAccount[]
            {
        new BankAccount()
        {
            Name = "Jack", Balance =150.08M
        }, new BankAccount()
        {
            Name = "James",Balance =70.45M
        }, new BankAccount()
        {
            Name = "Mary",Balance =200.01M
        }, new BankAccount()
        {
            Name = "John",Balance =200.01M
        }};
            Array.Sort(accounts);
            Array.ForEach(accounts, x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Name} {x.Balance}"));
        }

    }
    public class BankAccount : IComparable<BankAccount>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public int Balance { get; set; }         

        public int CompareTo(BankAccount other) =>
           (Balance,Name).CompareTo(
               (other.Balance,other.Name ));

    }
```

[Try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yh0him)