# Comparing objects in c#.net have some difficulty

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have problem in comparing two objects. I am struggling to find the difference between two objects. It gives me always same result.

Here is my object:

```
ClassA
{
    int slNo;
    string location;
    Dictionary dic = new Dictionary<string,Object>();
    ClassB classb = new ClassB();
}

ClassB
{
    int id;
    string name;
}
```

I have created an instance for classA and assigned some values.

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA{ dic = new Dictionary<string, object>, classb = new ClassB()};
```

and populated the obj with some values.

Copied the values to new object

```
var objNewA = obj;
```

and changed the classA like below.changed the value of obj.slNo = 100 and also changing some dic values collection. I can able to find the difference of slno using below method

```
 public static bool FindDifference(ClassA originalObject, ClassA changedObject)
 {
     foreach (PropertyInfo property in originalObject.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
         object originalValue = property.GetValue(originalObject, null);
         object newValue = property.GetValue(changedObject, null);

         if (!Equals(originalValue, newValue))
         {
              return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
 }
```

but the dictionary value change i cant able to figure it out. Its giving me the modified value in  both source and destination objects any help please?

Comment: You didn't copy anything.

Comment: You may want to read up on reference types. Both `objNewA` and `obj` refer to the same object.

Comment: im sorry, i didnt get you, any example please

Answer (score 1):

Writing var `objNewA = obj;` doesn't copy values from your original object, they just get the same reference. You have then 2 variables accessing the same object in memory, and modifying `obj` also applies to `objNewA`. You'll never find any difference between them.

What you can do is cloning you object, like in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp). You'll get two objects with two different references but property values will be the same.

About checking `dict`, i don't think that `Reflection` is the best way to go, as it can quickly get complicated to write and to maintain. Plus, your parameters are of type `ClassA`, you already have access to your properties, without `Reflection`.

If you need more generic behavior about comparing two `ClassA` objects, what about overriding `object.Equals` in you class definition ? You're returning a `boolean`, which means that you only what to check if check values are equals. For example, you can add this in `ClassA` :

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (obj == null || !(obj is ClassA))
       return false;
    else
    {
        ClassA other = (ClassA)obj;
        bool isEqual = // ... do all the checks you need, like comparing this.dict with other.dict
        return isEqual;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two objects, implement the IComparable interface.

[How to Implement IComparable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/c-sharp-interfaces-how-to-implement-icomparable)

Answer (score 0):

you are actually trying to compare two equals object.
The statement:

```
var objNewA = obj;
```

means "assign to objNewA the reference of obj", therefore any changes to obj will be present in objNewA.
If you want to *"clone"* an object instance, **your ClassA must implement ICloneable Interface**, and call **Clone()** method on the object you want to clone.

In the end, since you're comparing two custom classes, you have to implement **IEquatable** interface in order to use **Equals()**.
Once implemented you can do just

`originalObject.Equals(changedObject);`

in order to achieve you goal