# Sorting a list of objects of multiple data types

Tags: c#, list, class, sorting, reflection

I have this class in my code

```
class Stock
{
    public DateTime Date;
    public string Day;
    public double Open, Close, Diff;
    public int Volume;

    public Stock(double open, double close, double diff, int volume, string day, DateTime date)
    {
        this.Open = open;
        this.Close = close;
        this.Diff = diff;
        this.Volume = volume;
        this.Day = day;
        this.Date = date;
    }
}
```

In another class i want to create a bubble sort that will sort a List of Stocks (`List<Stocks>`) passed to it, i am having multiple issues with this the main problem is the data types, its not easy comparing two values when they could be a `string`, `int`, `double` or `DateTime`. I have done it with a method that uses `TryParse` to check for valid data type, but im looking for a nice clean solution, this is my attempt so far

```
public void BubblesortBy(int sortBy, List<Stock> Stocks)
{

    Type objType = typeof(Stock);
    FieldInfo[] fields = objType.GetFields();

    Stock temp = null;
    int loopCount = 0;
    bool doBreak = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < Stocks.Count; i++)
    {
        doBreak = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < Stocks.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Compare(fields[sortBy - 1].FieldType.ToString(), fields[sortBy].GetValue(Stocks[j]), fields[sortBy].GetValue(Stocks[j+1])))
            {
                temp = Stocks[sortBy + 1];
                Stocks[sortBy + 1] = Stocks[sortBy];
                Stocks[sortBy] = temp;
                doBreak = false;
            }
            loopCount++;
        }
        if (doBreak) { break; /*early escape*/ }
    }
}
```

The `int` passed to it determines whether to sort by, which is why i am using reflection so the variables are accessible by numbers.

1. Date
2. Day
3. Open
4. Close
5. Difference
6. Volume

Comment: I would recommend using a switch statement and doing comparisons based on the Data Type in your case blocks.

Comment: Are you implementing bubble sort as a learning exercise, or for practical purposes? For 99.9% of practical purposes, don't implement your own sorting algorithm.

Comment: @TimS. For learning, How would i efficiently check the data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't assume that the fields returned by [`GetFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will be in a certain order.

> The GetFields method does not return fields in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which fields are returned, because that order varies.

One option is to use [lambdas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) like LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does. Using generic types can also make your code more reusable, and make things like your `Compare` method simpler.

```
public void BubblesortBy<TSource, TKey>(Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
                                        List<TSource> stocks)
{
    int loopCount = 0;
    bool doBreak = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < stocks.Count; i++)
    {
        doBreak = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < stocks.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Compare(keySelector(stocks[j]), keySelector(stocks[j+1])))
            {
                TSource temp = stocks[j + 1];
                stocks[j + 1] = stocks[j];
                stocks[j] = temp;
                doBreak = false;
            }
            loopCount++;
        }
        if (doBreak) { break; /*early escape*/ }
    }
}
private bool Compare<T>(T l, T r)
{
    return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(l, r) > 0;
}

// use like
BubblesortBy(x => x.Close, myList);
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim S. for this answer, how would i call this as i am getting the error " The type arguments for method 'Stocks.Program.Sort.BubblesortBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.List<TSource>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly " with Sort.BubblesortBy(secondNumber, Stocks);

Comment: @Raymond I've added an example now. Use a lambda like `x => x.Volume` instead of an `int` to indicate which field to use to compare.

Comment: This answer is exactly what i was looking for, for understanding how does Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector work? i have never worked with IComparable functions before

Comment: @RaymondTunstill `Func<TSource, TKey>` is a delegate. `x => x.Close` is a lambda. You're not directly working with `IComparable` in any way, but `Comparer<T>.Default` does use that. Read up on each of these things to better understand what's happening here. If you break this code down into its components, it is quite comprehensible.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you implementing sorting yourself? Look into [IComparable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/c-sharp-interfaces-how-to-implement-icomparable/4188041#4188041)

Edit:

A nice and type safe way to pass the field to sort by into the method without refection, would be:

```
BubblesortBy(x => x.FieldName, stockes);

public void BubblesortBy<T>(Func<Product, T> sortBy, List<Stock> Stocks)
{
    Stock temp = null;
    int loopCount = 0;
    bool doBreak = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < Stocks.Count; i++)
    {
        doBreak = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < Stocks.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (Compare(sortBy(Stocks[j]), sortBy(Stocks[j + 1])))
            {
                temp = Stocks[sortBy + 1];
                Stocks[sortBy + 1] = Stocks[sortBy];
                Stocks[sortBy] = temp;
                doBreak = false;
            }
            loopCount++;
        }
        if (doBreak)
            break; /*early escape*/
    }
}
```

Comment: @RaymondTunstill added sample to my post