# How do I implement IComparable<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, comparison, icomparable, icomparablet

I've created my own generic Java data structure library, now I'm creating it in C#, but I'm stuck trying to implement the CompareTo method to sort a singly linked list.
Here's my code:

```
class SortedSinglyLinkedList<T> : IComparable // my class
// [irrelevant stuff...]
// Sorts the list, from the least to the greatest element
    public void sort()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                if (get(i).CompareTo(get(j)) < 0) // ERROR -> 'T' does not contain a definition for 'CompareTo' and no extension method 'CompareTo' accepting a first argument of type'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
                {
                    move(i, j); // this method simply moves a node from i to j
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Compares 2 elements
    int IComparable<T>.CompareTo(T other)
    {
        // what should I put here to make it work?
    }
```

Comment: I think you mean `class SortedSinglyLinkedList<T> where T : IComparable`. You want `T` to be comparable, not the list.

Comment: Check if answers in this question helps you:  [C# Interfaces - How to Implement IComparable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/c-sharp-interfaces-how-to-implement-icomparable?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving this, is to require the elements of your list to be comparable, i.e. have them implement the [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface. You would express this using a generic type constraint on `T`, as in:

```
public class SortedSinglyLinkedList<T> : where T : IComparable
```

A more general way of doing this, that also allows your list to contain elements that do not implement this `IComparable` interface, is to follow the strategy used in many of the c# BCL generic collection classes (e.g. [`SortedDictionary`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sorteddictionary.cs,1a01ea5555bded49) or [`SortedList`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/sortedlist.cs,de670561692e4a20)): use an [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instance to perform the comparisons.

```
public class SortedSinglyLinkedList<T>
{
    private readonly IComparer<T> _comparer;

    // ...

    public SortedSinglyLinkedList()
    {
        _comparer = Comparer<T>.Default; // use the default.
        // ...
    }

    public SortedSinglyLinkedList(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
        // ...
    }
}
```

And in your `Sort` method, use this comparer instance to perform the comparisons:

```
_comparer.Compare(get(i), get(j));
```

Comment: @Alan_UK, you are welcome. I just edited my answer, to include the links to the BCL sorted dictionary and sorted list implementations, so you can see for yourself how they make use of this.