# How does CompareTo method work while Implementing IComparable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, interface

I have a class:

```
 public class Customer :IComparable<Customer>
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Salary { get; set; }
        }
```

I also have a List:

```
Customer cust = new Customer() { Id=10,Name="Jack",Salary= 15000};
            Customer cust1 = new Customer() { Id = 10, Name = "Abby", Salary = 5000 };
            Customer cust2 = new Customer() { Id = 10, Name = "Zed", Salary = 152000 };

            List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
            list.Add(cust);
            list.Add(cust1);
            list.Add(cust2);
            CustomerList.Sort();
```

I understand why list.Sort wont work on Customer since Customer class has three properties and it does not know how to sort it. But if I implement the interface `IComparable` in `Customer` class I am able to sort the Customer List any way i want.

```
public class Customer :IComparable<Customer>
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Salary { get; set; }

            public int CompareTo(Customer other)
            {
                return this.Salary.CompareTo(other.Salary);
            }            
        }
```

Now my question is.. How does implementing CompareTo method let me sort `CustomerList`? I am not even overriding Sort Method or anything. 
I am confused since I have not used CompareTo method at all.

I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188041/2064292 but it does not answer my question.

Comment: Sorting is done by comparing items with each other to see which item should come first - if you have a sorting algorithm already (provided by the list implementation) all it needs to know is how to compare your items. It's up to you - when implementing `CompareTo` - to provide the logic that determines which of two `Customer` objects should come first.

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the MS website? It has a complete example of how you can implement the interface and how it is then used. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Igor I have already implemented the interface in the example. But I am not getting how that lets me make `CustomerList.Sort();` work?

Answer (score 4):

When you implement `IComparable<T>`, creating a `public int CompareTo(T)` method, what you are essentially doing is telling the sorting mechanism, which is defined elsewhere, *how* to sort two instances of your class by comparing one instance to another.

Like I said, the actual sorting mechanism is defined elsewhere, e.g. [`List<T>.Sort()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Whatever algorithm the sorting mechanism uses -- [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), [quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), etc. -- is irrelevant, but they all need to compare instances against one another over and over to produce their sorted result.  Each time two instances are compared, your `public int CompareTo(T)` method implementation is called because that's where you define *how* your specific implementations are compared to one another in order to produce the sorted result.

Comment: Is it possible to see the actual sorting mechanism of List<T>.Sort in visual studio? Also I am guessing that .Sort method of List uses CompareTo Method of IComparable behind the scenes. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah well I had typed the comment before I refreshed your post. But is it possible to see actual sorting mechanism in VS?

Comment: As to your first question, see this: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,2f4bb2904365726f

Comment: Thank you. It is helpful. I wonder how a newbie like me is supposed to learn all this? I mean I was watching videos on youtube randomly and just found out that when you provide an implementation of CompareTo method in class you can sort A List<T>. Had it not been for that video I might have never discovered.

Comment: @Arbaaz -- You're welcome.  My journey as a programmer/software developer started out almost 24 years ago.  Needless to say, it takes time and patience.  Keep at it.

Comment: 24 years. Wow. That's basically almost how old I am. I guess there are no short cuts. : )

Comment: @Arbaaz -- I started tinkering with [BASIC on Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_BASIC) when I was 12.  Yeah, it's like being a skilled doctor or master carpenter or anything else.  There are never shortcuts in life when trying to master a discipline.

Answer (score 1):

While there are a lot of different sorting algorithms, they all come down to the same thing:

> Move things around so that "lower" items come before "higher" items.

Therefore all sorts need to be able to understand "lower" and "higher" for the objects they are sorting.

This is easy enough with numbers; e.g. `3 < 4` is `true` because `3` is lower than `4`. Even just with numbers though we'd have to write a different sort algorithm for `int`, `long`, `decimal`, `double` and so on, because we can't use generics here (operators like `<` are not available through generics) and certainly can't use `<` on `object`.

So we need to define some mechanism by which .NET can provide default "lower" and "higher" logic for all sorts of numbers, along with strings etc.

We also can't do any sorting on types we don't know about, so again we need that mechanism to know which is "lower" and which is "higher".

`IComaprable<T>` and `IComparable` do that.

We also have `IComparer<T>` and `IComparer` to allow us to define custom orders (e.g. having different logic for case-sensitive and non–case-sensitve searches) or to allow someone to provide an order on a type that doesn't implement `IComparer`.

Sorts generally works as:

1. If we were passed an `IComparer<T>` object, use it to decide which is lower or higher.
2. If we were not passed an `IComparer<T>` then use `Comparer<T>.Default`.

The use of `Comparer<T>.Default` means we don't need a separate sort for when we don't have an `IComparer<T>`, we just use the default.

Now, `Comparer<T>.Default` works as follows:

1. If the type implements `IComparable<T>` call into that.
2. Otherwise if the type implements `IComparable` (the old interface from before generics) then use that.
3. Otherwise throw an exception, because there's no way to know how to order anything.

Comment: your answer is helpful. I wonder how would a newbie like me is supposed to learn that giving an implementation of CompareTo would let me sort List<Customer>? I mean I just found out about this randomly watching videos on youtube.

Comment: @Arbaaz if you have a problem using the `Sort()` method, the first place to look is  [the documentation for the `Sort` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which says, "The Comparer<T>.Default property checks whether type T implements the IComparable<T> generic interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not, Comparer<T>.Default checks whether type T implements the IComparable interface. If type T does not implement either interface, Comparer<T>.Default throws an InvalidOperationException."

Answer (score 0):

CustomerList is a generic List with a generic type parameter Customer.
The sorting algorithm implementation for the Sort() method is the one provided by the Generic List and by looking at the Microsoft documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx) you can see that actually three algorithm are used depending on the size of your list:

> - If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an insertion
>     sort algorithm.
> - If the number of partitions exceeds 2 * LogN, where N
>     is the range of the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.
> - Otherwise, it uses a Quicksort algorithm.

The algorithms all rely on your implementation of IComparable for the Customer class to know how to order your customer objects.

Answer (score 0):

Within the code for List<T>.Sort(), it will be

- casting each object to IComparable<T>,
- using that interface to call CompareTo(),
- the result from that call determines the sort order.

For example:

```
// Sorts a list using IComparable<T>
public static void Sort(this List<T> list)
{
   // Worst sorting algorithm ever
   for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; ++j)
      {
          // Assumes that type T implements IComparable<T>
          IComparable<T> first  = (list[i] as IComparable<T>);
          IComparable<T> second = (list[j] as IComparable<T>);

          if (first.CompareTo(second) > 0)
          {
              // wrong order
              Swap(list, i, j);
          }
      }
   }
}
```