# How to sort/Orderby List<object> result = new List<object>();?

Tags: c#, .net, list, object

I add Custom type: `Task` in to the list.

e.g.

```
Task t1 = new Task();

result.Add(t1);
```

Now i want to order `'result'` by the `EndDate` property of `Task` class.

Comment: Implement IComparable interface inside of the class and then you'll be able to sort a list containing elements of that type. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/c-sharp-interfaces-how-to-implement-icomparable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Sort a List<T> by a property in the object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object)

Comment: What is `result`? What have you tried to order them?

Comment: Duplicate was very first google result for "c# order by property"

Comment: If you're sure you have nothing but `Task` instances in your list, use [`Enumerable.Cast<Task>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), i.e. `var ordered = result.Cast<Task>().OrderBy(t => t.EndDate).ToList();`  But better to use `List<Task>` as everyone says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `List<Task>` instead of `List<object>` then you can use `OrderBy` Like this:

```
var sorted = result.OrderBy(c => c.EndDate);
```

Or:

```
var sorted = result.OrderByDescending(c => c.EndDate);
```

Or:

```
var sorted = result.OrderByDescending(c => c.EndDate).ToList();
```

Comment: But i have an existing code where List<object> has been implemented and used in many other references.

Comment: @MrudangDalal ...Well if you want to keep the `result` as a `List<object>` you can define another `List` like this: `List<object> result = new List<object>();

            List<Task> result2 = result.Cast<Task>().ToList();` and then: `var sorted = result2.OrderByDescending(c => c.EndDate);` If you didn't understand tell me so that I update my answer and explain it more.

Comment: Excellent. It worked. Actually after your suggestion i made it more easier.
List<Task> result = new List<Task>();
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.EndDate).ToList();
return result.ToList<object>();

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a `List<Task>` to be the type of `result`. Right now you have `List<object>` and you can't access `EndDate` property without casting.

```
List<Task> result = new List<Task>();
Task t1 = new Task();
result.Add(t1);
```

and then for sorting you can use `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending`

```
var sortedQuery = result.OrderBy(r=> r.EndDate);
```

If you need a `List<Task>` then append `ToList();` to the query.

*Also, you may change your class name to something different, as there is a [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) 
class available in .Net framework as well*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ by a typed List<>.

For example:

```
List<Task> result = new List<Task>();

result.Add(Task1);
result.Add(Task2);

return result.OrderBy(x => x.EndDate).ToList();
```