# Using IComparable to compare arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, inheritance

I have a problem with a school task.

"Let's say class List are constructors to generate random arrays.

Class List1 inherits from class List and uses IComparable to compare first elements, then second ones etc. (blank is a 0) {1,1,1}<{1,2}<{2}

Class List2 inherits likewise and compares sizes of arrays by size. If sizes are the same, check like in List1 {1,2,3}<{1,2,3,4}<{2,2,3,4}"

I made class List.

```
  public List(int b)
      {
          tabb = new int[b];
          for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
              tabb[i] = r1.Next(0, 100);
      }
```

I noticed that inheriting from List to List1 the constructors are not inherited, so i dont know where and how to use IComparable

```
class List1 : List,IComparable<List1>
  {
    public int CompareTo(List1 x){
      return this.CompareTo(x);
    }
  }
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/how-to-implement-icomparable-interface This should help you.

Comment: I've read this topic. Still struggling with inheritance though

Comment: @OskarJaglak This is **not** C++, please fix your tags according to the language you are actually using.

Comment: What is the struggle?

Comment: What really throws this for a loop is that the requirement specifies random numbers. (Not saying you - it's the assignment they gave you.) There are a number of scenarios that have to be tested for. In real life I'd want to write unit tests to account for them so I know it works. It's not impossible to account for both testing and dealing with random numbers but it's a complication *if* you want to be able to write unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that inheriting from List to List1 the constructors are not inherited, so i dont know where and how to use IComparable

I can't comprehend that sentence as a single question, as the lack of constructors being inherited seems completely independent to me of how to use `IComparable<T>`.

So, let's address the two questions separately:

1. You are correct that constructors are not inherited. That is, while they still exist, they are callable only by the derived type, and not directly usable by outside code. If a base class does not have a parameterless constructor, then as the implementer of the derived class, it is your responsibility to provide a constructor and then call the appropriate base class constructor (every class will have *some* constructor). For example:

```cs
class List1 : List
{
    public List1(int count) : base(count) { }
}
```

(I'm assuming here that `List` is some type other than the .NET `List<T>` type, i.e. it's not generic and is defined in your own context.)

In this way, you provide the necessary constructor, and ensure that the correct base constructor is called, by using `: base(count)` to pass the parameter value to your constructor.

2. How to use `IComparable<T>`. It seems to me that this is the crux of your assignment. I would be doing you a disservice to write the code for you. However, I'll try to elaborate on the instructions to help you understand what they seem to be asking (of course, your teacher is the best person for you to receive this advice from).
   You have two different assignments here. Both require that you implement the interface `IComparable<T>`, so the first thing you need to do is make sure you understand what it means to implement an interface. Do you? An interface is a kind of "contract". In any interface declaration, there are described the members that an implementation of that interface is required to provide. If you look at [the definition of `IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see it requires implementation of just one member: a `CompareTo()` method.
   So, your assignment comes down to how to implement that method for each of the two required subclasses, `List1` and `List2`. The basic idea of the implementation is the same for both, but the specifics are different.
   In the first case, the comparison will order the two instances of `List1` according to the contents of the collection where the order of those instances is determined by the ordering of the first non-equal element in the same position of the array in each instance. In the examples given, `{1, 1, 1}` is treated as "less than" `{1, 2}` because when you compare the elements at each position for each instance of `List1`, the first corresponding position where the elements are different is the second position (index `1`), where `{1, 1, 1`} has the value `1` and `{1, 2}` has the value `2`. The value `1` is less than the value `2`, so the whole instance of `{1, 1, 1}` is "less than" the whole instance of `{1, 2}`. (Unfortunately, the assignment as described in your post is not clear on how to order instances where the underlying list of one is shorter than the underlying list of the other, but has exactly the same values in those element positions. I would make the shorter list be treated as "less than", but that's not unambiguously the only valid way to do it.)
   In the second part of the assignment, implementing `List2`, the only thing that's being compared is the *length* of the list. This should be much easier to implement than the first part of the assignment, because you have only a single value to compare in each `List2` instance, i.e. `tabb.Length`.
   Note that in both cases, you can take advantage of the fact that `int` also implements `IComparable<T>`, so you can use its `CompareTo()` method to determine whether corresponding values in each instance of your class are less than, equal to, or greater than each other.

I hope that that's enough to get you pointed in the right direction. If you need more help than that, you probably should just consult with your instructor. They will know exactly how much help they want to provide to you, while remaining short of actually doing the assignment for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I didn't mean to go all out on this. But then it just happened. It's late. It interested me, especially the need to be able to test it even though the requirement for random numbers makes it difficult to test.

The solution I came do was to separate the list from how it gets populated. That way for test purposes I can substitute a "populator" that inserts exactly the values I want. That way I can create the scenarios for testing.

```
// This is the base list - it just requires something to populate it.
public class IntegerList : List<int>
{
    public IntegerList(IIntegerListPopulator populator, int size)
    {
        populator.PopulateList(this, size);
    }
}

// Interface and implementation to populate a list with random numbers.
public interface IIntegerListPopulator
{
    void PopulateList(List<int> target, int size);
}

public class RandomIntegerListPopulator : IIntegerListPopulator
{
    public void PopulateList(List<int> target, int size)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            target.Add(random.Next(0, 100));
        }
    }
}

// Compares by values, but the populator is injected - needed so that
// the class can be tested.
public class IntegerListThatComparesByValues : IntegerList, IComparable<IntegerListThatComparesByValues>
{
    public IntegerListThatComparesByValues(IIntegerListPopulator populator, int size)
        : base(populator, size)
    { }

    public int CompareTo(IntegerListThatComparesByValues other)
    {
        return new IntegerListValueComparer().Compare(this, other);
    }
}

// Class to perform comparisons by value. There's no real point 
// in implementing IComparer since I'm not using it that way,
// but it doesn't hurt.
public class IntegerListValueComparer : IComparer<IntegerList>
{
    public int Compare(IntegerList x, IntegerList y)
    {
        // I made this part up. I don't actually know how
        // you want to handle nulls. 
        if (x == null && y == null) return 0;
        if (x == null) return 1;
        if (y == null) return -1;

        // Always compare the longer one to the shorter.
        // if this one is shorter, do the reverse comparison
        // and reverse the result.
        if (y.Count < x.Count) return -Compare(y, x);
        if (x.SequenceEqual(y)) return 0;
        for (var index = 0; index < x.Count; index++)
        {
            var comparison = x[index].CompareTo(y[index]);
            if (comparison != 0) return comparison;
        }

        // If the other list is longer than this one, then assume
        // that the next element of this list is 0.  
        return -y[x.Count];
    }
}

public class IntegerListThatComparesByLength : IntegerList, IComparable<IntegerListThatComparesByLength>
{
    public IntegerListThatComparesByLength(IIntegerListPopulator populator, int size)
        : base(populator, size)
    {
    }

    public int CompareTo(IntegerListThatComparesByLength other)
    {
        var comparisonByCount = Count.CompareTo(other?.Count ?? 0);
        return comparisonByCount != 0
            ? comparisonByCount
            : new IntegerListValueComparer().Compare(this, other);
    }
}

// *************************************************************
// These are the concrete classes specified in the requirements.
// *************************************************************

public class RandomIntegerListThatComparesByValues : 
    IntegerListThatComparesByValues
{
    public RandomIntegerListThatComparesByValues(int size)
        : base(new RandomIntegerListPopulator(), size)
    { }
}

public class RandomIntegerListThatComparesByLength : 
    IntegerListThatComparesByLength
{
    public RandomIntegerListThatComparesByLength(int size)
        : base(new RandomIntegerListPopulator(), size)
    { }
}

// *************************************************************
// The rest is all testing.
// *************************************************************

// Allows me to create class instances that contain the numbers
// I specify instead of random numbers so that I can create 
// test cases.
public class IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble : IIntegerListPopulator
{
    private readonly int[] _values;

    public IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(params int[] values)
    {
        _values = values;
    }

    public void PopulateList(List<int> target, int size)
    {
        target.AddRange(_values.Take(size));
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class IntegerListThatComparesByValuesTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void EmptyListsAreEqual()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(), 0 );
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(), 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, list1.CompareTo(list2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ListsWithSameValuesAreEqual()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1,2,3), 3);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1,2,3), 3);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, list1.CompareTo(list2));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ListsOfSameLengthComparedByFirstNonEqualValue()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 4), 3);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3), 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(list1.CompareTo(list2) > 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MissingElementsOfListAreSortedAsZeros()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3, 4), 4);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3), 3);
        var comparison = list1.CompareTo(list2);
        Assert.IsTrue(comparison > 0);
        comparison = list2.CompareTo(list1);
        Assert.IsTrue(comparison < 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MissingElementsOfListAreSortedAsZeros_Case2()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3, -4), 4);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByValues(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3), 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(list1.CompareTo(list2) < 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(list2.CompareTo(list1) > 0);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class IntegerListThatComparesByLengthTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ListsAreComparedByLength()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByLength(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3, 4), 4);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByLength(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3), 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(list1.CompareTo(list2) > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(list2.CompareTo(list1) < 0);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ListsOfEqualLengthAreComparedByValue()
    {
        var list1 = new IntegerListThatComparesByLength(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 4), 3);
        var list2 = new IntegerListThatComparesByLength(new IntegerListPopulatorTestDouble(1, 2, 3), 3);
        Assert.IsTrue(list1.CompareTo(list2) > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(list2.CompareTo(list1) < 0);
    }
}
```

I don't know if they teach unit testing in school, but this illustrates why they should. While the logic isn't incredibly difficult, it's likely that the first stab at it isn't going to be perfect. Without creating some test cases to run against this, how could you know if you got it right? How would your instructor know? What if you fix one bug but in doing so break the other test case? And then if you have to debug, every single time you debug you get different random numbers. Scary.

(It was the randomness that really threw me off. If the numbers are always random, how does the instructor expect to observe the results and know that they're correct? It's possible but eyeballing it isn't the most reliable way to know that it works.)

In real life, I wouldn't want to put even slightly complex logic into a production system without having these unit tests to tell me that it works as expected.

Also, when you read a description of requirements it can be confusing and unclear. But assuming that I understood the requirements, now you can look at the unit tests and get a clearer idea of what this code is supposed to do. Otherwise someone else could need to make changes, and if they can't tell what it's supposed to do, they can't tell if they're breaking it. If it turns out that I got the requirements wrong then I can change the tests to fit the right requirements. The tests will fail and then I modify the code until the tests pass.