# Implement IComparable with strings

Tags: c#, string, interface, icomparable

I have class Employee and I need to implement IComparable and use CompareTo method to sort employees by name. From what I've seen, I have to return 1, -1, and 0, but how do I use the strings?

Here's what I have.

```
class Employee : IComparable<Employee>
{
    string name;
    string address;

    public int CompareTo(Employee obj) 
    {
        Employee person = obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at string.Compare https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Implement IComparable interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188013/how-to-implement-icomparable-interface)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing to do is to just pass it through to an already implemented comparison method.  In this case, since you just need to compare two strings, you could just call `String.Compare`:

```
class Employee : IComparable<Employee>
{
    string name;
    string address;

    public int CompareTo(Employee obj) 
        => string.Compare(name, obj.name);    
}
```

You could use `name.CompareTo(obj.name)` too, but then you'd need to worry whether `name` might be null.  According to [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22(v=vs.110).aspx) on `String.Compare`:

> One or both comparands can be null. By definition, any string, including the empty string (""), compares greater than a null reference; and two null references compare equal to each other.

Comment: Does => mean change to?

Comment: It's just shorthand for a single-command method. The technical name for it is an "expression-bodied member"

Comment: It means the same thing as { return ...; }

Answer (score 0):

Simple :

```
        public int CompareTo(Employee obj)
        {
            if (name == obj.name)
            {
                return address.CompareTo(obj.address);
            }
            return name.CompareTo(obj.name);
        }
```

Comment: I dont need to use the address